# substitution in an irrational integral

Tags: integration

I solved this irrational integral $$ \int \frac{1+\sqrt{x^2+3x}}{2-\sqrt{x^2+3x}}\, dx$$
doing the substitution

$$ x= \frac{t^2}{3-2t}$$
according to the rule,

The final result is $$ \frac{t}{2}+\frac{9}{4 \cdot (2t-3)}+ 3 \ln|3-2t|-\frac{12}{5} \ln |t-1|+\frac{12}{5} \ln |t-6|$$

Now I have to substitute $t$ with something with $x$.

From: $$ x= \frac{t^2}{3-2t} \Rightarrow t_{1/2}=-x \pm \sqrt {x^2+3x}$$
.

The book chooses $x=-x +\sqrt {x^2+3x}$ but I don't understant why .
Can someone show me the reason?

Comment: The principle root of a quadratic is the one associated with the $+$ sign.

Comment: Either one should work.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$t_{\pm}=-x \pm \sqrt {x^2+3x}\implies \sqrt{x^2+3x}=\pm \frac{3t-t^2}{3-2t}
$$

Since $ \sqrt{x^2+3x}=\frac{3t-t^2}{3-2t} $
is used to arrive at the result, the back substitution should be $t=-x+ \sqrt{x^2+3x}$.

Comment: why should  $t-x$ be necessarily positive?

Comment: @Anne - $t+x$ could be either positive or negative, depending on the sub $t=-x \pm\sqrt{x^2+3x}$. You had the positive choice

Comment: What I can't see is the necessity of having $t+x$ positive seen that I can obtain the same thing

Comment: @Anne - you could use the sub $t=-x- \sqrt{x^2+3x}$ to integrate as well. The result will be equivalent, though looking different